# Не могу присвоить значение выхода StandardScaler() к новым колонкам дата фрейма

Tags: pandas, sklearn

В `modify_data` этих колонок не существует, во второй строчке я их создаю и присваивая

```py
scaler = StandardScaler()
modify_data[[num_cols]] = scaler.fit_transform(data[num_cols])
```

Ошибка:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['ClientPeriod', 'MonthlySpending',
 'TotalSpent'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Для теста:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
url='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-tf97Hjklw_eHFxeup36bBpElSC1hrb/view?usp=sharing'
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + url.split('/')[-2]
data = pd.read_csv(url)
num_cols = [
    'ClientPeriod',
    'MonthlySpending',
    'TotalSpent'
]
#Убираю пустые строки в TotalSpent
data.TotalSpent = data.TotalSpent.apply(lambda x: float(x) if x.split() else 0)
modify_data = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Кажется тут одни квадратные скобки лишние `modify_data[[num_cols]]`

Comment: @CrazyElf так и есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
modify_data[[num_cols]] = scaler.fit_transform(data[num_cols])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Я проверил на ваших данных, очевидно у вас просто одни квадратные скобки лишние, `num_cols` - это и так уже список колонок, не нужно его дополнительно помещать в список. Правильно так:

```py
modify_data[num_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(data[num_cols])
```

У меня при этом в `Google Colab` выходила другая ошибка на вашем коде:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Вероятно, у вас другая версия `Pandas`, либо код был не совсем такой, как вы показали для воспроизведения ошибки. Но суть проблемы и решения от этого не меняется.